# Windows 7 + NVidia == 640x480 on external projectors

Tags: windows-7, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, projector

I have a MacBook Air which has the NVidia 9400M. The problem is, when I connect it to an external projector on Windows 7 and Vista, it only allows me to connect at 640x480.

I need it to use the laptop to present at conferences, as such I need it to work on a number of different projectors - at the moment I need to use OSX and VMWare but it's painfully slow and doesn't work.

Is there any way to override the screen resolutions provided? I've saw some information around EDID.

Comment: Should point out, it works fine with OSX

Comment: The projector(s) you've tried *do* have a native res higher than 640x480, right? Just trying to rule that out...

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/51004/13-macbook-pro-with-win-7-and-external-vga-gets-640x480

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed with Bootcamp 3.1. I've verified the fix.

Install from the [Apple website](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/)

Comment: Yep, installed the update and working happily now. Tried with multiple projectors...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the newest drivers for your card? If you don't know, download and install for the windows drivers for the geforce 9M series at the [nVidia driver website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). I can't link to the exact one because you didn't specify if you are using the 32 or 64-bit os but I think you can figure it which one you need yourself.

If it's not that, or you already did an update, then you have a bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird as as the projector should simply be seen as another screen by your computer. The graphics card in your laptop should be more than sufficient.

Have you checked what the maximum resolution of the projector is?

Lastly, the Mac Book Air is really designed for portability - not as a power house. Whilst VMware will work on it, do not expect any miracles speed wise.