# 13" MacBook Pro with Win 7 and External VGA gets 640x480

Tags: windows-7, macbook, external-display, projector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 + NVidia == 640x480 on external projectors](https://superuser.com/questions/26884/windows-7-nvidia-640x480-on-external-projectors)

I have a brand new 13" MacBook Pro - 2.26 GHz and the NVIDIA 9400M Video card.  I installed Windows 7 (final) in boot camp and booted up to Windows 7.  Installed all the drivers from the Apple disk and it was working great.  Then I attached the external VGA adapter (from apple) to connect to a projector and it dropped down at 640x480 resolution.  No matter what I did it wouldn't let me change to a higher resolution if the external VGA was connected.  Once it disconnects then it goes back to the normal resolution.

If I am booted into Snow Leopard it works fine.

I tried updating the NVIDIA drivers and it behaved exactly the same.

Ultimately I want to get 1024x768 or better resolution when connected to an external display.  If it isn't fixable then I am curious if anyone else has seen this, if it is a known issue, and who to contact for support (Apple, Microsoft or NVIDIA?)

**Update:** Just attaching the Mini-DVI to VGA adapter kicks it into 640x480, no projector is required.  I tried forcing the display driver from Generic PnP Monitor to one that supported 1024x768 and that didn't work either.

Comment: Looking over this question, it seems to be a possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/26884/windows-7-nvidia-640x480-on-external-projectors. Maybe merging them would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed with Bootcamp 3.1. I've verified the fix.

Install from the [Apple website](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/)

Answer (score 3):

It will not help you much, but just to let you know yor are not the only one:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1972917&start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Actually it is good to know it is a known issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you've tried updating drivers, but try using the latest from [**LaptopVideo2Go**](http://laptopvideo2go.com/). Make sure you are not booting with the projector plugged in. Plug it in after Windows has loaded then check display preferences, you should be able to increase the resolution.

Comment: I installed the latest driver from there, and now I can go to **lower** resolutions.

Comment: The max VGA resolution supported by that card is 2048x1536, your adapter is likely the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problems, but ONLY with projectors. If I plug the DisplayPort to VGA adaptor to an external monitor or LCD television I can select higher resolutions, but only 640x480 is available when I attach a projector! Crazy.